# How to run a post request in qt main()

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to do a simple post request int main.cpp. it would seem the when i run the application it would not execute the code and just skips it.

I tried using the qt debugger but the code below after the debugger start it just finishes right after.

I have tested my api with postman and knows it works

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkInterface>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
QByteArray jsonString = "{\"ipaddr\": "+ QByteArray::number(9) + ",\"transactionType\":"+QByteArray::number(10) + ",\"idEmployee\":"+QByteArray::number(10) +"}";


QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://192.168.1.25:3000/classlog/pi"));
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
manager->post(request, jsonString);

}
```

.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
QT += network core

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

I expect that i would be able to receive the request in my server, but i am not receiving any. Thank you

Comment: ypu have to connect the slots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt uses an event system. Your the network manager will only schedule a request that will be handled in an event loop. This is also where the response is received.

You need a running event loop (and in fact, a `QCoreApplication` object, you sould get a warning when executing your code).

```
#include <QtNetwork>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"));
    auto *resp = mgr.get(req);
    QObject::connect(resp, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
        qDebug() << "FINISHED";
        if (resp->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
            qDebug() << "Error: " << resp->errorString();
        else
            qDebug() << "Status: " << resp->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toString();

        // Stop when a response is received
        app.quit();
    });

    // This will start the event loop that will eventually send the request and receive the response.
    // It will run until you call app.quit()
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this actually worked and also I now have an idea of what these QApplications are and do

Comment: QCoreApplication executes the event loop, amongst other things. Look at [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#details](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#details) for more detailed information.

Another way of thining of it: You designed a nice car, but without QCoreApplication::exec() you never started the motor so it didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there:

```
connect the signals:

QtObject::connect(your_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(onResult(QNetworkReply *)));

send something:
QNetworkRequest request(your_URL);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
QByteArray byteArray;
byteArray.append(your_json);

your_manager->post(request, byteArray);


read the answer in the slot:
void FOO_CLASS::onResult(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QString resp = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
}
```

edit
:

```
QObject::connect(your_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [](QNetworkReply * r){
    QString x{r->readAll()};
    //foo1
    auto l{x.length()};
    //foo2
});
```

Comment: im not using classes, this is inside main (). i am try to do a non class aproach of posting

Comment: use a lambda then

Comment: You should also mention that a `QCoreApplication` and its event loop is required.

Comment: with the code i am just fetching the reply right? but right now i do need the reply. currently i am having trouble for the server to receive my request.

Comment: @king_nak can you please elaborate sir ?

Comment: @Jack See my answer